# Mega Bloks Set Identification with large pieces AM09249 and AM09250

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

Does anyone know which set these parts are from?
I have two of them.
Labeled AM09249 and AM09250.

[image]

Comment: That might be one of the most obscure looking piece I have seen. It's also quite unusual how two of the studs are hollow.